# User Profile Service - missing user profiles from AD

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, profile-sync, fim

I have 2 SP 2013 SP1 environments, testing and production. Both have user profile service application (using FIM agent) configure to get profiles from AD. Both the farms have similar service connection and filter settings but production is missing a few users who are present in test environment.

I have run full profile multiple times and checked the connection filters, user account is not disabled hence present in test farm. I checked the ULS of production and found the following for one of the missing user:

> Returning AD resolve match 'i:0#.w|domainA\user' for input 'domainA\user'.
>
> User profile record of "domainA\user" was changed by "domainB\farm_account".

We have one forest with multiple domains but all configuration in test and production are similar hence I'm confused as to why one farm imports the users when the identically configured other farm fails to import them.

Any suggestions/recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: You could continue troubleshooting by analyzing messages in the FIM-Console (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe). Please do not apply any changes there!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there are errors on profiles not visible in the GUI. You could try the following script and do a sync again then the script has finished.

```
Get-SPServiceApplication
#Copy the ID an replace <identity> in the following line
$upa = Get-SPServiceApplication <identity>
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -GetNonImportedObjects $true
#When you need to execute, run the following:
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this script before posting the question here. We had lots of orphan users and this script + running profile sync again got rid of those users. But I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: @Manu There's nothing more to do, unless you have additional issues on this topic.

Comment: I guess this is how it is then, if there is nothing in the logs we are stuck with whatever it is.

Comment: @Manu You may have to run it several times before everything is OK. In serious cases I created a task scheduler rule that made the script run every night.